# Where to setup Python environment attributes for a Django project?

Tags: python, django, decimal, environment

For example the Python `decimal.Decimal()` class has a context. You can view the current context with `getcontext()` and set new values for precision, rounding, or enable traps.

If you wanted to set a new value for the context so this is visible throughout a Django project, where would be best to do so?

e.g. Throughout the project the `FloatOperation` signal should be trapped.

```
from decimal import FloatOperation, getcontext

context = getcontext()
context.traps[FloatOperation] = True
```

Also using `getcontext()` return the current context for the *active thread*. Aside from explicitly creating new threads in a project, are there any additional consideration to make with Django creating additional threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest an application `core`, or `common`, that includes your setup as part of `AppConfig.ready()`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready